# What does the GCC error message, "Error: unsupported for `mov'", mean?

Tags: linux, assembly, gcc, system-calls, inline-assembly

I am just trying to compile some simple example code I typed in from a book, and GCC gives me the above error.  Here's my code:

```
$ cat -n test.cpp

 1  #define READ_COMMAND    3
 2  
 3  #define MSG_LENGTH  128
 4  
 5  #include <stdlib.h>
 6  #include <stdio.h>
 7  
 8  int main(int argc, char *arg[])
 9  {
10      int syslog_command = READ_COMMAND;
11      int bytes_to_read = MSG_LENGTH;
12      int retval;
13      char buffer[MSG_LENGTH];
14  
15      asm volatile(
16          "movl %1, %%ebx\n\t"
17          "movl %2, %%ecx\n\t"
18          "movl %3, %%edx\n\t"
19          "movl $103, %%eax\n\t"
20          "int $128\n\t"
21          "movl %%eax, %0"
22          :"=r" (retval)
23          :"m"(syslog_command),"r"(buffer),"m"(bytes_to_read)
24          :"%eax","%ebx","%ecx","%edx");
25      if (retval > 0) printf("%s\n", buffer);
26  
27  }
28  
29
```

The code is supposed to invoke the `syslog()` system call to read the last 128 bytes from the kernel `printk()` ring buffer.  Here is some information about my OS and system configuration:

`uname -a`:

> Linux 3.2.0-26-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 17:49:24 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

`gcc -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
```

> Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu

```
Thread model: posix

gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

Heres the full error:

```
$ gcc test.cpp

test.cpp: Assembler messages:

test.cpp:25: Error: unsupported for `mov'
```

Comment: Is that the entire message? For what line of code is it?

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers; it makes it much more difficult to copy-and-paste it. Just add a comment showing which line is #25.

Comment: I tried it on my system (Ubuntu 12.04, gcc versions 4.6 and 4.7). When I compile it *as C* (with a `.c`, not `.cpp`, file extension), it compiles and links without error. I get an odd segfault when I run it; I don't know enough about what it's supposed to do to understand that.

Comment: Same problem, but caused by hand-writing an instruction with mismatched register sizes: [Unsupported instruction \`mov\`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70308621)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are attempting to compile 32-bit assembly code on a 64-bit machine. The inline assembly you list compiles to:

```
movl -24(%rbp), %ebx
movl %rsi, %ecx       <--- error here
movl -28(%rbp), %edx
movl $103, %eax
int $128
movl %eax, %r12d
```

As you can see, you're attempting to store a 64-bit register in a 32-bit register, which is illegal. More importantly, this isn't the 64-bit ABI system call protocol either.

Try compiling with `-m32` to force 32-bit ABI.

Answer (score 2):

you should use "movq" to move 64 bits value.

see like this:

```
int main(void) 
{
  long str_len = 15;
  const char* str = "hello world!\n\r";

asm volatile(
    "movl $4, %%eax\n\t"
    "movl $1, %%ebx\n\t"
    "movq %0, %%rcx\n\t"
    "movq %1, %%rdx\n\t"
    "int      $0x80\n\t"
    :       
    :"r"(str), "r"(str_len)
    :"eax","ebx", "rcx", "rdx"
);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Yes, that would get it to compile, but note that it's pointless to use 64-bit registers for `int 0x80`; the 32-bit system call is only going to look at the 32-bit register.  ([What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)).  So you could do `mov %k0, %%ecx` to force it to print the 32-bit register name when expanding `%0`, instead of whatever width it picked based on the C var.

Comment: Or better, use a `"c"(str)` constraint to ask for the pointer in ECX/RCX in the first place, so you don't need any `mov`, *just* `asm("int $0x80" : "=a"(retval) : ...  )` as the template with no clobbers needed, not forcing the compiler to find different registers for the inputs.

Comment: Also note that the key thing was using a 64-bit destination register, not just the `movq` mnemonic.  You could use plain `mov` and let the assembler infer the operand-size.  So yes, this does answer the question about `mov` sizes, but for a system call wrapper this is the worst possible way to go about it, and basically wrong to use int 0x80 instead of syscall for 64-bit code.  Hopefully useful to people using `mov` for other reasons, though.

Comment: Also, Linux uses just `\n` for newline, not DOS `\r\n`, and certainly not `\n\r` (used nowhere).