# Unsupported instruction `mov`

Tags: assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly, att, gnu-assembler

I'm studying about basic shell code with *orw* code.
But, in the process, I've got this error message:

> Error: unsupported instruction `mov`

This is my skeleton code in C and assembly:

```
// File name: orw.c
// Compile: gcc -o orw orw.c -masm=intel

__asm__(

    ".global run_sh\n"
    "run_sh:\n"

    "push 0x67\n"
    "mov rax, 0x616c662f706d742f \n"
    "push rax\n"
    "mov rdi, rsp\n"
    "xor rsi, rsi\n"
    "xor rdx, rdx\n"
    "xor eax, eax\n"
    "mov eax, 2\n"
    "syscall"
    "\n"
    "mov rdi, eax\n"
    "mov rsi, rsp\n"
    "sub rsi, 0x30\n"
    "mov rdx, 0x30\n"
    "xor eax, eax\n"
    "syscall"
    "\n"
    "mov rdi,1\n"
    "mov eax,1\n"
    "syscall" 
);

void run_sh();

int main() { run_sh(); }
```

I have put `movq` and `movl` but they didn't work.

Why does this problem occur with my code?
What is the solution?

Comment: `mov rdi, eax` is invalid because you try to move a 32 bit register into 64 bit. You probably want `mov rdi, rax`.

Answer (score 6):

Use `gcc -save-temps` to save compiler output to a file so you can match up the line number with the actual asm line.  (Or put your asm into a `.s` file to feed directly to `as`).

**It's the `mov rdi, eax` that's the problem; the problem is the operands, not the mnemonic.**

There are a couple different forms of `mov` (which is perhaps why you get such a useless error message<sup>1</sup>), but the one that takes general-purpose integer regs for both operands needs them to both be the same size.

To zero-extend `int fd = open(...)` from EAX into RDI, use `mov edi, eax`.
See [MOVZX missing 32 bit register to 64 bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387571/movzx-missing-32-bit-register-to-64-bit-register) for more about why that's the instruction for zero-extending.

Footnote 1:
[GP and segment regs](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov), mov [to/from control regs](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov-1), mov [to/from debug regs](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV-2.html), and also mnemonics like `movq xmm, xmm/mem` that need to be disambiguated from `mov` with and AT&T-syntax `q` suffix.  See [What does AT&T syntax do about ambiguity between other mnemonics and operand-size suffixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990177/what-does-att-syntax-do-about-ambiguity-between-other-mnemonics-and-operand-siz)

---

Also, you can optimize  `mov rsi, rsp` ; `sub rsi, 0x30` into `lea rsi, [rsp-0x30]`.
And yes, x86-64 SysV has a red-zone, so it is fully safe in user-space to use up to 128 bytes of space below RSP, even across `syscall` on Linux.

If not for that, you'd want to `sub rsp, 0x30` / `mov rsi, rsp`. (But if you want to eventually `ret`, you'd need to undo that to point RSP back at the return address.)

Comment: Oh, it works...I made a mistake!Thank you a lot!!

Comment: @eunseo: If that solves your program, you should click the "accept" checkbox under the vote arrows.